# Spreading props in react while maintaining reference equality

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Imagine that I have a function which dynamically generates some of a component's props, and I want to pass them all at once without being explicit about every prop the function could generate. Normally you can do this with the spread operator, but the issue with the spread operator is that it created a new object each time. This would mean that (if I understand correctly) during the [React Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html), the component would have new props every time and would rerender every time, even if the props the function generated are the same.

Here's a concrete example:

```
const generateProps = () => ({foo: 'bar'});

const ParentComponent = () => ({
   const someProps = generateProps();

   return (
      <SomeComponent><ChildComponent {...someProps} otherProp='hello world'/></SomeComponent>
   )
})
```

Here ChildComponent would render every time `ParentComponent` would render (right?). One thing I know you could do is wrap the `ChildComponent` with a `React.memo` and do a deeper comparison of the props (passing a custom comparison function to it), but what if you don't have control over `ChildComponent`? Are you forced into being explicit? Or am I incorrect and `ChildComponent` wouldn't rerender in this example (assuming `ChildComponent` simply consumes the props and doesn't use any contexts or anything).

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it wrong. Reconciliation doesn't look at the props. It mainly looks at the component type, e.g.

if on one render you render

```
<Comp1/>
```

and on next render, on the same place in the component tree, you render:

```
<Comp2/>
```

it will unmount `Comp1` and mount `Comp2` because the type of components is different. If component types are the same, it will update existing one. There are some more details but you can check them yourself.

Furthermore, the props are also compared in a shallow way by default if you use `React.memo`, so if on one render you pass

```
let y = {a:1,b:2};
....
<Comp1 {...y}/>
```

and on next render you pass

```
let x = {a:1,b:2};
...
<Comp1 {...x}/>
```

Default comparison of `React.memo` will assume that props didn't change, because `a` and `b` have same values.
You can verify here, clicking on the `div` *doesn't* re render the `Test` component:

```js
 

let Test = React.memo(props => {
  console.log(props);
  return <div>{props.a}</div>;
});

function App() {
  let [state, setState] = React.useState({ a: 123 });
  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => {
        setState({ a: 123 });
      }}
    >
      <h1>Hello StackBlitz!</h1>
      <Test {...state} />
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(
    <App  />,
    document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  <div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: I apologize, when I brought up React.memo I meant you could pass a custom comparison function to do a deeper check of the props.
And I completely had it wrong with Reconciliation, however React does decide whether to rerender components based on props. So my question becomes, is how you pass the props irrelevant then? (as long as the prop values have shallow equality)

Comment: @Eli I added example to the answer check it. If you don't use `React.memo`, when parent re renders all of its children will re render, even if props are the same.